# Change waveform into binary in Saleae Logic Analyzer

Tags: logic-analyzer, saleae-logic-analyzer

I'm using this famous logic analyzer and I would like to know if I can change the waveform into binary, like I've done in this pic (white numbers).

[image]

Comment: yes, you have to enable the protocol analyzer for that data stream ... it is on the right side of the screen

Comment: If you operate it with sigrok (and maybe pulseview) instead of the Saleae software you can write your own protocol decoders in python, or pipe the data into something in the language of your choice.

Comment: Logic (the app) isn't going to know the relationship between your waveforms unless it's defined somehow - which is clock, which is data, when data should be read (rising edge/falling edge) with respect to the clock, so no there will be no heurestic decoding of this signal in my estimation.

Comment: @ChrisStratton nice - I wrote an analyser in C++ with the salae sdk but didn't know python was also possible - oooh!

Answer (score 1):

Your channel labels (MISO, Clock, CS) are perfectly consistent with standard SPI protocol.  Just add an SPI analyzer and assign your rows accordingly:

- MISO <- MISO
- Clock <- Clock
- Enable <- CS

You'll probably have to play with the polarity (CPOL) and phase options (CPHA) to get it to match your particular signal.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a protocol analyser from the centre of the right-hand panel. It will software-decode the waveforms into packets of whatever protocol you are investigating. From there, you can specify the radix as binary to get a binary output.

If you are looking at arbitrary waveforms, I'm not sure the software will reliably decode it. But at that point, a protocol analyser couldn't tell you any more than simply looking at the screen!

Comment: I know that, but this it not any standard protocol. I just want to get the binary code from a data line according to a clock line. I think there's no protocol analyzer for that, right?